# C# MVC, Link Together Nested Partial Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In a C# MVC WebApp, I have a `CallDetailViewModel` that contains a list of `CallerViewModels` and it has a List of `PhoneNumberViewModels`. I'm trying to link them all together properly.

Not shown here, but I am also trying to both load existing values and add new/remove values, so I don't know what's being sent to the controller ahead of time.

I've tried following this 2012 guide that has a very similar problem I found online, but no luck yet: [Code Project Article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/434886/Dynamically-adding-controls-on-a-hierarchical-stru)
I also tried moving the List of `PhoneNumberViewModels` to the `CallDetailViewModel`, and while I was able to pass the phone numbers to my controller I didn't have a clear way to link them to the appropriate `CallerViewModel`.

I want to be able to add and remove `PhoneNumbers` from `Callers` and `Callers` from the `CallDetail`.
I've removed my buttons and AJAX regarding those for now, as it's not my main problem.

Here are my simplified ViewModels and Views:

### ViewModels

**CallDetailViewModel.cs**

```cs
namespace PROJECT_NAME.ViewModels
{
    public class CallDetailsViewModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string EnteredByEmail { get; set; }

        public List<CallerViewModel> CallerViewModels { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**CallerViewModel.cs**

```cs
namespace PROJECT_NAME.ViewModels
{
    public class CallerViewModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public List<PhoneNumberViewModel> PhoneNumberViewModels { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**PhoneNumberViewModel.cs**

```cs
namespace PROJECT_NAME.ViewModels
{
    public class PhoneNumberViewModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Views

**CallDetail.cshtml**

```html
@using PROJECT_NAME.ViewModels
@model CallDetailsViewModel

<div class="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitCallDetails", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        <div class="well">
            @* Call Details *@
            <div class="row">
                <fieldset">
                    <legend>Call Details</legend>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EnteredByEmail, new {@class = "control-label"})
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EnteredByEmail, new {@class = "form-control"})
                </div>
            </div>
            @* Caller Details *@
            <div class="row">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Callers</legend>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            @* Render each existing caller. Each caller gets it's own well to create a visual seperation between them. *@
            @if (Model.CallerViewModels.Count == 0)
            {
                <div class="well">
                    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialCallerInfo", new CallerViewModel());}
                </div>
            }
            @foreach (var callerViewModel in Model.CallerViewModels)
            {
                <div class="well">
                    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialCallerInfo", callerViewModel); }
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset">Reset</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**_PartialCallerInfo.cshtml**

```html
@using PROJECT_NAME.ViewModels
@model CallerViewModel

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("CallerViewModels"))
{
    <div class="row">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control"})
        </div>
    </div>
    @if (Model.PhoneNumberViewModels.Count == 0)
    {
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialCallerPhoneNumber", new PhoneNumberViewModel());}
    }
    @foreach (var phoneNumberViewModel in Model.PhoneNumberViewModels)
    {
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialCallerPhoneNumber", phoneNumberViewModel); }
    }
}
```

**_PartialCallerPhoneNumber.cshtml**

```html
@using PROJECT_NAME.ViewModels
@model PhoneNumberViewModel

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("PhoneNumberViewModels"))
{
    <div class="row">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Number, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Number, new { @class = "form-control"})
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: The `BeginCollectionItem()` method does not support nested collections. An alternative is to use the `HtmlHelper` methods described in [this article](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/06/06/editing-and-binding-nested-lists-with-asp-net-mvc-2/). Or if you want a pure client side solution, refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I8q07y)

Comment: Sorry for such a long delay in my reply, I've been trying to implement in my code the examples you linked to. I ran into obstacles with both implementations, unfortunately. In the article, where he makes a "small amendment to the HtmlPrefixScopeExtensions BeginCollection method", I start to get errors stating method ambiguity (and I was having some editor templates not appearing correctly as well like how it showed in the previous steps), and the pure client version I honestly don't remember what wall I hit there before switching to the article.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but with my Xmas vacation coming I won't be able to return to this for a little over a week at the earliest. If I'm able to come back to this and get to a solution I'll let you know. Thanks again!